# Opening Excel File with ClosedXML throws System.ArgumentNullException

Tags: openxml, closedxml

Every time I try to open an Excel file with ClosedXML with the following code

```
XLWorkbook spreadsheetDocument = new XLWorkbook("Sample.xlsx");
```

I get a System.ArgumentNullException. However, I made a copy of that file in Excel, I renamed it and I have opened it succesfully. I compared both files using the Open XML Productivity Tool and I got the following output.

[image: Output Open XML Tools]

I wonder if those differences have something to do with the fact that I cannot open Sample.xlsx using ClosedXML. Thank you for your help.

Comment: do you have more information about that exception? for example call stack, or exception message?